# if __name__ == __main__ not working after compilation

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing

i'm actually working on a script using multiprocessing library, everything is working perfectly from my text editor ( VSC ):

```
import multiprocessing

def example_func():
    print("This is a targeted function for multiprocessing")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is the main session, starting multiprocessing")
    multiprocessing.Process(target=example_func).start()
```

so in my text editor when i run the code it output this :

```
This is the main session, starting multiprocessing
This is a targeted function for multiprocessing
```

but after I compile it to .exe using pyinstaller, something very strange happens, the code starts getting looped infinitely, its like if after i compiled it, the processes were considered as the main session, it means that in `if __name__ == "__main__"` processes were considered as **main**.

Please guys help, i really need your help.

EDIT : some guys told me to add string, I have already had it as a string in my script.I just didnt copy well here

Answer (score 4):

You need to [use `multiprocessing.freeze_support`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) appropriately when you're freezing to a Windows executable:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()  # Required for PyInstaller
    print("This is the main session, starting multiprocessing")
    multiprocessing.Process(target=example_func).start()
```

Without it, the Windows "fork-like" behavior `multiprocessing` relies on doesn't know where to stop executing code when it launches subprocesses with the same executable.

Answer (score 1):

It is a string:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Note the double quotes instead of `__main__` as an object (?).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why it didn't throw an error there but the `__main__` should be a string `'__main__'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare `__name__` to `string` `__main__`

```
import multiprocessing

def example_func():
    print("This is a targeted function for multiprocessing")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("This is the main session, starting multiprocessing")
    multiprocessing.Process(target=example_func).start()
```